# Can you do a range order in uniswap when the ratio is 1:1?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3

Let's say we have token1 / token0 and the WETH-USDC pool on uniswap. Range orders may only be performed in the higher priced token above the price and the lower priced token before.

Said differently if price is 1900 range orders providing only liquidity in WETH can only be done above the price and in USDC below the price.

But what if the tokens are equal in value? The real world use case I'm thinking of is stablecoin to stablecoin.

Does the transaction fail? Does it allow both tokens? Does it allow both stables above/below?

And one step further what happens if the ratios swap while you have a position? I'm assuming your funds wouldn't get locked but I would also assume they wouldn't convert either.

Any details would help.